# How to get a specific node from url link in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, url, nodes

how do i get a specific node from an URL in VBA. My XML-Doc is looking like this and is saved in a Custom-URL. How do i get whats between the Nodes "from".

The Code i already have looks like this:

```
Dim sPageHTML  As String
Dim sURL As String
Dim XmlMapResponse As String

sURL = "http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/xml/note.xml"

Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
oXMLHTTP.send
XmlMapResponse = oXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim strXML As String
Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim XDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60

strXML = XmlMapResponse

Set XDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

If Not XDoc.LoadXML(strXML) Then
    Err.Raise XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , XDoc.parseError.reason
End If

Set xNode = XDoc.selectSingleNode("//note/to/from")

Debug.Print TypeName(xNode)
Debug.Print xNode.XML


<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set xNode = XDoc.selectSingleNode("//note/to/from")
```

to

```
Set xNode = XDoc.SelectSingleNode("//note/from")
```

and change

```
Debug.Print xNode.XML
```

to

```
Debug.Print xNode.nodeTypedValue
```

or

```
Debug.Print xNode.Text
```